# Grouping Umbraco document types in the content page

Tags: umbraco

I have document type called `Page`.

If i go to the **Content** part and create a new `Page`, I expected there to be a node called **"Page"** and then under it, all `Page` i created.

This is not the case.

Do i instead have to make another document type called `Pages` and then allow child nodes of `Page`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the Content tree as the site map for your website - typically you would have a Home node at the top of the tree, then the content pages would sit directly underneath that.

So you might have a DocumentType called "Home" and one called "Page" - the Home DocumentTypewould be configured to allow Page nodes to be created under it.  It wouldn't make much sense to group the pages according to their type.

For example, here's the relationship between the Home Content node and things like Article Listings on our website (found under the Structure tab on Home):

[image: Allowed child node type - Home DocumentType]

And here's my content tree structure:

[image: Content Tree Structure]

The "Journal" and "Code" nodes are based on the Article Listing Document Type while the "Digitalsmith - ..." node is based on the Home Document Type for which the Allowed child node types is configured above.

This way, my content tree reflects my website structure; I've also utilised other visual cues to determine what type of Document each node is in the form of icons so it's easy for me to determine what kind of content I cam expect to be editing etc.

Comment: So if i create a Document type called `Pages` then that has child content of Document type `Page`, then my client can go to the "Pages" node under the "Content" tab and create a "Page"... If I need a different template for the "Page", I can create a `Home` template or a `Contact` template and put the corresponding ActionResult methods into the PageController which allows me to bring out the correct view I create... Does this sound about right?

Comment: Each DocumentType can have multiple Templates, with the option to choose a default.  When you create a Content node, you can specify which of the associated Templates you want to render the content with.  A Template is normally a Razor View and is by default located in the ~/Views directory.  If you want to use MVC Controllers then you probably want to read up here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Implementation/Controllers/